# My grudge with REST: am I right here or am I missing something?

Tags: sql, rest, design-patterns, xml-rpc

I am designing a data-centric application that stores sale orders
on a server. At any time the client may decide to modify a sales
order, perhaps because they receive a phone call from the purchaser
requesting additions, modifications, and deletions, associated with
the sale order. Thus each Sale database table on the server has a
SaleItems detail table where the sale items are stored.

Now REST methods GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE are supposed to correspond
roughly to SQL SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements to be
carried out on the server when the corresponding objects change.

If I use REST, when the order changes I would have to do a PUT to
update the sale item, thus calling an UPDATE statement. But then
the PUT would also need to: 1. delete all old items appearing as
purchase items, with their item quantities and item prices,
and then 2. insert all the new items with their quantities and
prices. Thus a PUT actually corresponds to an UPDATE, DELETE,
and multiple INSERTs (and I cannot think of another better way
to do this). So, so much for rest.

I cannot separate the SQL UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERTs because the
operation needs to be atomic and run within a single transaction,
so I cannot do an HTTP PUT, a DELETE, and multiple POSTS, as that
would be impractical.

So, when the HTTP operations do not correspond to the SQL operations
in a neat manner, what is the whole purpose of REST as opposed to
XML-RPC??? Have I misunderstood REST?

Thanks for your views.

Comment: "Now REST methods GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE are supposed to correspond roughly to SQL SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements"? No. They simply _happen_ to mostly correspond.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot separate the SQL UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERTs because the
>   operation needs to be atomic and run within a single transaction

You do misunderstand REST.  REST means REpresentational State Transfer.  In REST, you cannot modify an order by sending a command to delete an order line.  That would mean sending unrepresentional state.

Instead, you send the complete order with all changes you've made.  In other words, you Transfer a REpresentation of the State of the order.  Sending a change that way is transactional.